# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 18: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python

I'm trying to output a datetime column to json.But I'm getting this error in Python 2.7:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 18: invalid continuation byte
```

This is a sample data:

```
>>> data
            id impact_date             store     country  \
0      6244543  2017-10-10  ARGENTINA   ARGENTINA
1      6244544  2017-10-10  ARGENTINA   ARGENTINA
2      6244545  2017-10-10  ARGENTINA   ARGENTINA
3      6244546  2017-10-10  ARGENTINA   ARGENTINA
```

This is my code:

```
data = get_data(DB_ENGINE, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_PORT, MYSQL_DB, query)


if filename:
    with open(filename, 'w+') as f: f.write(json.dumps(x,default=datetime_handler))

def datetime_handler(x):
    if isinstance(x, datetime.datetime):
        #return unicode(x.strftime("%B %d, %Y"),errors="ignore")
        # return unicode(x.strftime("%B %d, %Y").encode('latin-1'),errors="ignore")
        return x.strftime("%B %d, %Y").encode('ISO-8859-1')
    else:
            return x
    raise TypeError("Unknown type")


if filename:
    with open(filename, 'w+') as f: f.write(json.dumps(x,default=datetime_handler))
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT

The full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 18: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: **1** Is this Python 2 or 3? **2** What line is raising that error? Please post the full traceback. **3** When writing encoded bytes to files (rather than text) you should open those files in binary mode. That shouldn't matter on Unix-like systems, but it does on Windows. **4** It's not a good idea to mix encodings, eg ISO-8859-1 with UTF-8. And definitely don't mix encoded data with unencoded Unicode strings. You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Hi this is Python 2.7. I posted the full traceback. The full code is this. I only don't show get_data function, which is just a function to access my database.